# earthEngine: count number of fully covered pixels within a region

Tags: google-earth-engine, reducers

I would like to count the number of pixels that are fully covered by a given region/geometry. How can I do that? Using standard reducer, I can get:

- `ee.Reducer.count()` will just count the number of pixels whose centroid is included in the geometry. In the example, 6.
- `ee.Reducer.histogram()` will do a weighted count of the number of pixels that have at least 0.5% covered by the geometry. Here 6.31
- `ee.Reducer.histogram().unweighted()` does some strange stuff I don't get. Here 11

But none of these solutions counts the number of fully covered pixels, here 2. How can I do that?

[image]

#### Code

Available at: https://code.earthengine.google.com/615a60459b5a025eca34e3e42cf78496?noload=true

```
var rectangle = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-92.53867, 40.18690],[-92.53867, 40.18638],[-92.53750, 40.18638],[-92.53750, 40.18690]]], null, false);
var CDL_2015 = ee.Image('USDA/NASS/CDL/2018')
  .select('cropland')

//count
var hist_1 = CDL_2015.gt(0).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.histogram().unweighted(),
  outputPrefix: "_unweighted",
  sharedInputs: true}),
  geometry: rectangle,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
})
print(hist_1)

var hist_2 = CDL_2015.gt(0).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram(),
  geometry: rectangle,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
})
print(hist_2)

var count = CDL_2015.gt(0).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: rectangle,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
})
print(count)


//////////////////
// Visu
/////////////////

Map.centerObject(rectangle)
Map.addLayer(CDL_2015.clip(rectangle.buffer(20)), {}, "CDL_2015")
Map.addLayer(ee.FeatureCollection(rectangle).style({width: 3, color: "blue", fillColor: "#00000000"}), {}, "CLU_here")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When applying ee.Image.clip(), partial pixels will have decimal values, between 0 and 1. You can use this to mask your image before reducing.

```
var mask = CDL_2015
  .clip(rectangle).mask()
  .eq(1) // Partial pixels will have value < 1. Mask them out

var masked = CDL_2015.updateMask(mask)

var hist_1 = masked.gt(0).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram().unweighted(),
  geometry: rectangle,
  scale: 30
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/87e6c55c2020c71841853543ca18e2ae?noload=true

Comment: perfect, thanks! I tried to also visualize the layer with the coverage values, trying to plot `mask` or `masked`, but to no avail. How would you plot that? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a image projected with rectangle pixels, such as your CDL image, you will 99.9% of the cases be right when you use the `count()` reducer, with a slightly contracted geometry. This reducer indeed incorporates all the pixels which contain their center within the geometry. To make sure no redundant pixels are contained in the geometry, subtract half the scale from the geometry you apply the reduction on. That's easily done using `buffer(-halfPixel)`. In the case of your image, the scale is 30m, so we contract the geometry by 15m:

```
var count = CDL_2015.gt(0).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: rectangle.buffer(-15), // subtract half the scale from geometry
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
})
```

Hope it works! [Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/abc6f31b1af2353de226ae9b3d5e5680?noload=true) with another test.